# Dynamically increase height of a div as many times a loop runs in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, multidimensional-array, height, dynamic

I have a PHP multidimensional array which will store information depending on parameters input.

Now as many times the loop runs, I want it the background div height to increase. The structure of HTML layout is as below:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++)
 {
  <div id='outer div'> --------------------------background color rounded corner
       for($j = 0; $j< $array[$i]; $i++)
       {
            <div id='inner div'>

                    contents

            </div>
       }
  </div>
 }
```

Please advice.

I know I should use javascript code like $("#outer div").height(), but how to pass this value to javascript?

Thanks a lot...
Mark and Krister,

Thanks for helping me out and telling me that I can use the inline way to set height. However your code had problem.

Instead of: height = $array[$i] * 10; This worked: height = count($array[$i]) * 10; // remember it was array of arrays (Multidimensional array).

Comment: Are you using javascript for rounding the corners ? I thing height should increase according to content.

Comment: No Vikas, I am having css for doing rounded corners.. I tried using  Javascript to increase height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `inline css` like this:

```
 <div id='outer div' style="height:<?php echo $i*10; ?>px;">
```

Comment: np, you should accept a answear if you think it's correct and helped you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use such a complex solution, just give the div no height and it will expand dynamically. You also need to look a templating solution instead of hardcoding HTML in your code.

Comment: Could you suggest some template solutions?